# How do dark color varies from people when seeing the back of their eyelids?

Tags: optics, vision, biology

Depending on the light source, the back of people's eyelids either be black or dark gray depending on what lit environment they're in? the how does eyes function when people have the back of their eyelids a dark color?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced both red and orange, as well as more rarely green. It depends a lot on how bright the environment is, the color of the light, and how firmly you close your eyes. The reason is that the eyelid is fairly transparent to red light, which can more easily shine through. If you use your muscles to close the eyelid firmly it will be thicker and more light will be absorbed, making the experience more black.

Comment: it varies from people that see the back of the eyelids sees dark colors, I usually see the back of my eyelids, black or a grayish color.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the eyes in a lighted environment reduces overall intensity to night light intensity. At this level the three color photon detecting cone cells are switched off and the visual brain activates the recognition nerves to gray level rod cells only. They have a higher photon capture efficiency but come only in one kind, so they deliver a black and white image.

Completely shutting of outer photons  input in a dark room sets all response levels to zero intensity Poisson noise, no difference for rods and color cones. The brain is free to interpret the noise by its fantasies. If you close the eyes suddenly with the hands, you see the last picture for approximately 20 s, the receptor transmitter resorption period, about the same time, you begin to see in darkness by the rods, if you enter a very dark room.
.
If you press the lid in darkness, a theater of colored forms appear.

[Photo receptor cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoreceptor_cell)

Comment: If you close your eyes with your hands, you see an afterimage, I usually a afterimage of the screen on the chormebook when I close my eyes, like a  camera, our eyes are exposed to light, so when we see the insides of our eyelids, we generally see a dark color due to the photons, but it varies person to person.